# What is the minimum number of items in a B-tree of order m and height h?

Tags: data-structures, b-tree

The maximum number of items in a B-Tree of order m and height h is defined by the equation [image: i sub max equals m to the power of h plus one, minus one]

Or, in text format:

```
m^h+1 - 1
```

But I am looking for the formula for the minimum number of items.

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15027739/what-are-the-minimum-number-of-keys-a-node-must-contain-for-a-b-tree-of-order-n), but the answer isn't related.

Comment: No i want to know @wheaties

Comment: I Googled this: http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus5/html/page339.html Does that answer your question?

Comment: awesome, I'd mark it as an answer but it's not my answer, I just Googled it. Happy hacking.

Comment: @wheaties I think its better to mark it.

Answer (score 1):

The following solution uses the definitions by Thomas Cormen.

For a tree of the height 0 you will get 1 as a minimum, of course.

For a tree of the height 1 you will get 2 successors for your single node with each containing

`ceil(t/2)`

nodes at minimum.

So you can say, that in each layer greater than 1 you will have at least

`2*(ceil(t/2)**(h-1)) * (ceil(t/2)-1)`

The 2 comes from the first layer where a single element with two successors is allowed. Every node i between has at least ceil(t/2) successors. In the base layer you will have ceil(t/2)-1 nodes. That is the third part of the formula.

Using the geometric sum formula for all heights from one to h, you will get:

`2*(ceil(t/2)-1)*((1-ceil((t/2))**h)/(1-ceil(t/2)))+1`

`t` being the order of your tree and `h` being the height.

Answer (score -1):

Its.  2.Ceil(m/2)^h-1
.........